# How does floor not have a main type?

Tags: fortran

```
/home/disk/p/atms380/xx/October-Runs/timeManMod/SourceMods/time_manager.F90(664):
error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit
type.   [FLOOR]
tmd = day_earth/PLANET_DAY_RATIO - floor(day_earth/PLANET_DAY_RATIO)
```

I'm running Fortran 90 with the ifort compiler. As far as I can tell, floor is a function introduced in Fortran 90

```
Using Fortran compiler: ifort  -O -I/home/disk/eos11/bitz/cam3.1/cam1/models/utils/esmf -I/home/disk/eos11/bitz/cam3.1/cam1/models/utils/esmf/src/include -I/home/disk/eos11/bitz/cam3.1/cam1/models/utils/esmf/build/linux_intel -I/home/disk/eos11/bitz/cam3.1/cam1/models/utils/esmf/include   -I/home/disk/eos11/bitz/cam3.1/cam1/models/utils/esmf/src/Infrastructure/mpiuni                         
Fortran Compiler version:
Intel(R) Fortran Intel(R) 64 Compiler Professional for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 11.1    Build 20091130 Package ID: l_cprof_p_11.1.064
```

==

This is how I defined the PLANET_DAY_RATIO in the subroutine:

```
subroutine get_curr_date(yr, mon, day, tod, offset)

! Return date components valid at end of current timestep with an optional
! offset (positive or negative) in seconds.

implicit none

! Arguments
integer, intent(out) ::&
yr, &! year
mon, &! month
day, &! day of month
tod ! time of day (seconds past 0Z)

integer, optional, intent(in) :: offset ! Offset from current time in seconds.
! Positive for future times, negative
! for previous times.

! Local variables
character(len=*), parameter :: sub = 'get_curr_date'
integer :: rc
type(esmf_date) :: date
type(esmf_time) :: off
integer :: ymd
integer :: leap_days
integer :: yZero
integer :: day_earth
float :: PLANET_DAY_RATIO

(stuff)

yr = ymd/10000
mon = mod(ymd, 10000) / 100
day = mod(ymd, 100)
PLANET_DAY_RATIO = 0.5 !0.5 is for spinning twice as fast, or 43200 seconds
yZero = start_ymd/10000
leap_days = (yr -yZero)/4
day_earth = day_earth + 365*(yr -yZero) + leap_days
tmd = day_earth/PLANET_DAY_RATIO - floor(day_earth / PLANET_DAY_RATIO)

end subroutine get_curr_date
```

Comment: What is the compiler you are using? mpif90 is not a compiler, but merely an mpi binding.

Comment: Oh I see. Apparently I'm using ifort (intel fortran compiler)

Comment: try gfortran or ifort 12 and see if that works

Comment: Is type `float` an ifort extension? Can you cut this down to a minimal, self contained, compilable example that exhibits the same problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not looking at the right mistake !

The variable **PLANET_DAY_RATIO** is not correctly declared : **float** is not a valid real number declaration. Replace **float** by **real** please.

About the surprising warning of the compiler, it is simply due to the fact that the function FLOOR is generic : the compiler needs to know the type of the argument to select the right FLOOR variant function. As the argument was incorrect, the compiler has deduced that FLOOR was an identifier of your program (yes ! it is authorized to declare variables or functions which match Fortran intrinsic function names because Fortran is a language without reserved keyword).